# example numbering (gb4e) changes between overlays (beamer)

Tags: beamer, numbering, overlays, linguistics, gb4e

I am trying to include overlaid gb4e glossed examples in a beamer presentation. However when changing between overlays, the example numbering for the same examples also changes. The code below is a pair of such examples

```
\begin{frame}

\begin{exe}
    \ex<1>
    \label{13}
     \gll Mening uning bilen k\"{o}r\"{u}sh-\myemphred{k\"{u}}-m bar.\\
\textsc{1sg.gen} \textsc{3sg.gen} with meet-\textsc{inf-poss.1sg} \textsc{ext.aff}\\
`I would like to meet him.' \hfill{(T\"{o}m\"{u}r 2003)}

     \ex<2>
     \label{14}
     \gll Al-\myemphred{mak}-ning ber-\myemphred{mik}-i bar, chiq-\myemphred{maq}-ning ch\"{u}sh-\myemphred{mik}-i bar.\\

take-\textsc{inf-gen} give-\textsc{inf-poss.3sg} \textsc{ext.aff}, ascend-\textsc{inf-gen} descend-\textsc{inf-poss.3sg} \textsc{ext.aff}\\

`For every taking, there is a giving, for every ascending, there is a descending.' \hfill{(T\"{o}m\"{u}r 2003)}
 
\end{exe}


\end{frame}
```

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead put your fragment into a compilable document that people can play with. Because this fragment doesn't compile.

Comment: But independent of that, `gb4e` macros are not overlay aware, and so there's not an easy fix to this problem, although there may be some hacks that you could use manually.